# ngx-cookie-service is not returning the data on page refresh

Tags: angular, ngx-cookie-service

I am using `ngx-cookie-service` and setting the values on login

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.loginServie.login(this.model)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          this.loading = false;
          // Handle login error
          console.error('Login failed:', error);
          return throwError(() => error); // Rethrow the error
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          // Handle successful login response
          this.loading = false;
          this.cookieService.set('employeeId', response.employeeId);
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
      );
  }
```

On `Dashboard.service.ts` I am using as follows

```
export class DashboardService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService, private cookieService: CookieService) { }
  getTimesheetDataByEmployee()> {
    return this.configService.getConfig().pipe(
        switchMap((config: any) => {
            const empId = this.cookieService.get("employeeId");
            console.log("EmployeeId : " + empId);
            const environment = config.environment.isLocal ? 'local' : 'dev';
            const baseUrl = config[environment].baseUrl;
            const url = `${baseUrl}/TimeSheet?eid=${empId }`;
            return this.http.get<any[]>(url);
        })
    );

  }
}
```

on the browser console, I can see it is logging the employeeid value but when coming to the angular console I couldn't see any which is throwing an error from the service

Browser console

[image]

Angular terminal
[image]

On refresh this is happening on the first attempt after login it works well. Can someone tell me what is going wrong

Ok this is what I find when I have this method with out error block it works fine

```
getEmployeeTimesheetData() {
     this.isLoading = true;
     this.dashboardService.getTimesheetDataByEmployee(this.cookieService.get("employeeId")).
       subscribe((data: any[]) => {
         this.isLoading = false;
         this.employeetimesheetData = data;
         this.groupTimesheetDataByMonth();
       });
   }
```

When I am handling with pipe it throws an error

```
getEmployeeTimesheetData() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.dashboardService.getTimesheetDataByEmployee(this.cookieService.get("employeeId"))
    .pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        // Handle error here, e.g., log error message or show error to user
        console.error('Error fetching employee timesheet data:', error);
        return throwError(() => error); // Rethrow the error to propagate it downstream
      })
    )
    .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.employeetimesheetData = data;
      this.groupTimesheetDataByMonth();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SSR Enabled, that might be the reason why you are getting that error, because normally angular console does not show `console.log` errors. You can just use `isPlatformBrowser` to bypass this check since there is no browser cookies on the server!

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
...
private fromBrowser: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platform: Object) {
   this.fromBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platform);
  }
}
...
```

Comment: This is happening only on refresh if I go this way like login and navigate to dashboard after successful attempt it works fine. But once when I am dashboard and refreshing the page this happens

Comment: @Developer are you using SSR? is it possible to replicate on a stackblitz?

Comment: Hmm I am seeing a weird behaviour actually for the first time I am unable to see the value from cookieservice but not sure why the api is hitting multiple times and on the second time I can see the value

Comment: `Naren Murali` any idea as per the second update I made why this is happening

Comment: @Developer please share how you are calling `getEmployeeTimesheetData` if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Comment: on ngOnInit `ngOnInit() {
    const employeeId = this.cookieService.get("employeeId");
    if (!employeeId) {
      this.getEmployeeTimesheetData(employeeId);
    }
  }`

Comment: @Developer can you debug the API that gets failing on the network tab, and let me know what parameter is not coming properly? also check if you are clearing cookieService anywhere!